# bash pass "if" conditions as arguments?

Tags: bash

is it possible to pass conditions that are checked in if clauses (https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) as arguments to a function? The following does not work.

```
print_message_if_condition_holds() {
  local CONDITION="$1"
  local MESSAGE="$2"

  if $CONDITION; then
    echo "$MESSAGE"
  fi
}

print_message_if_condition_holds [ 0 -eq 0 ] "Success"
```

can it be done with somewhat different syntax?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how advisable it is, but you could do it by treating each token as a separate positional parameter. Since conditionals may take varying numbers of tokens (`[ -z str ]`, `[ str ]`, `[ n -lt m ]` and so on) you can't hard-code for the parameters - but provided there is only a single `messaage` then you could swap the order and do

```
print_message_if_condition_holds() {
  local message=$1
  shift
  local condition=("$@")

  if "${condition[@]}"; then
    echo "$message"
  fi
}

print_message_if_condition_holds "Success" [ 0 -eq 0 ]
```

Somewhat related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: not bad already, this doesn't seem to work for 'or' conditions though, such as `[ 1 -eq 0 ] || [ 0 -eq 0 ]`

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann that's true yes - in general, everything after the first *control operator* will be considered part of a separate *simple command*

Comment: You could try composing conditions like `COND="( $a -eq $b -o $c -ne $d ) -a -n $e"`, then pass that string to the `test` or `[` command such as `if [ "$COND" ]`.

Comment: Or, pass the arguments to `[` to the function: `print_message_if_condition_holds() { local msg=$1; shift; [ "$@" ] && echo "$msg"; }` -- then `print_message_if_condition_holds "Success"  "$a" -eq "$b"`

Comment: @glennjackman yes indeed that sounds like a more robust solution

Comment: What am I missing?  How is glenn's answer more robust than steeldriver's original answer? The only benefit I see is that glenn's answer saves you the bother of typing `[` and `]` — but it prevents you from doing things like `print_message_if_condition_holds "Files are identical" cmp -s file1 file2`.